# How to embed a dialog in a menu

Tags: gtk

I am recreating the [project hamster extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/425/project-hamster-extension/) from gnome as a xfce4 panel plugin.

The Gtk+2 recreation is realized as a menu and all the required widgets can be embedded in a vbox since the menu itself is a GtkBin:

[image: dropdown]

However I have no idea on how to disable the usual menu behaviour with highlighting (blue in image), focus stealing and enabling input to the text entry box or receive clicks of the tree-view.

Any ideas?